# Excel, after spilt column, how can I get the last part of a path in a new colum?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have just spilt a path in columns. I would like to take just the last part of every row, just the name of the filename(.doc or .pdf) and cut and put in a new column.

How can I do it in excel?[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Thanks
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWAsN.png

Comment: in some row the last part is in the column B , in another column C, and another column D

Answer (score 1):

Get all your filenames into one column using index and match.

```
=INDEX(A1:E1,1,MATCH("*.*",A1:E1,0))
```

I placed this formula in column F.

Then use `find` to locate the `.` then use `mid` to extract the extension.

```
=MID(F1,FIND(".",F1,1),LEN(F1) - FIND(".",F1,1) + 1)
```

I placed this formula in column E.

Comment: Thnaks...  A1 is the name of the new colum? where I want to put the new value? thanks a lot, that´s very helpful

Comment: in some row the last part is in the column B , in another column C, and another column D

Comment: A1 is the cell it is extracting the extension from. You should probably normalize your data...

Comment: how can I do that in excel with string values??

Comment: I mean put all the full names in one column instead of spread randomly.

Comment: that´s what I want to do it but I don´t know how

Comment: Just move the data? I don't understand what there is not to know.

Comment: yes, but the pictures is just an example, my excel has a million of rows

Answer (score 1):

`=LOOKUP(2,1/(A2:E2<>""),A2:E2)` entered with `ctrl+shift+enter` and copied down.